# Calculating in-duct sound intensities from sound pressure measurements with mean mass flow

Tags: acoustics, intensity, plane-wave

In the time domain and in free field condition the sound intensity can be calculated as $ \vec I(t)=p(t) \cdot \vec v(t)$ with $p(t)$ being the sound pressure and $\vec v(t)$ being the sound velocity. With $\vec v=- \frac{1}{\rho} \int_0^t \frac{p_2-p_1}{\Delta r}dt$ using 2 pressure measurements at locations with the distance $\Delta r$ and the air density $\rho$ the sound intensity can be calculated from 2 pressure measurements alone.

I am now looking for a way to calculate the sound intensity in a duct with mean airflow in the timedomain from 2 or 3 pressure measurements with known distances. So far I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243521690_On_the_multiple_microphone_method_for_measuring_in-duct_acoustic_properties_in_the_presence_of_mean_flow) paper which calculates the sound field for a plane wave propagation in a duct with mean flow from multiple pressure measurements. The measured pressure spectrum $P(x,f)$ at position $x$ is explained by the interaction of an incident ($P_+$) and a reflected ($P_-$) pressure wave.

$$ P(x,f)=P_+(f) e^{-i((k-i \delta)/(1+M))} + P_-(f) e^{i((k-i \delta)/(1-M))}$$

By using multiple pressure measurements at distances $x_1, x_2, ...$ a least-square approach can be used to calculate the 2 plane waves.

My question is, knowing the 2 plane waves, how do I calculate the in-duct sound intensity? Further, as the method from the paper works in the frequency domain, I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the in-duct sound intensity in the time domain?

Tube / duct with 6 sound pressure measurement locations (https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/article/Transmission-Loss-using-an-Impedance-Tube):
[image: Tube / duct with microphones]